# What level spells can a level 3 paladin cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin, spell-slots, spellcasting

Paladins don't get access to spellcasting until level 2.

Once they are level 2 can they now cast both level 1 and level 2 spells in their list or only level 1 spells (since they couldn't cast anything at level 1)?

I have not played any D&D in 15 years, and now I will DM a one-shot for my wife, which will be my first time DMing in 20 years. We want to learn the rules to join a more experienced group.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and check out [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9185/48759) for other places you can get help, or you can ask me in comments with @linksassin. This site is for all rpgs and the correct way to show which system you are using is by including the relevant tag. Thanks for participating and happy gaming.

Comment: Hi and welcome, mjmiller! I recommend watching a YouTube video of a group that plays 5e as well. It will help reinforce the rules in a live scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Two 1st level spells

The [paladin table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/Paladin#ThePaladinTable) from the basic rules shows the spell slots by class level. For a third level paladin they get **two 1st level spell slots** to cast their spells from.
From the [paladin Spellcasting feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/Paladin#Spellcasting-263) we have:

> You prepare the list of paladin spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the [paladin spell list](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=4&filter-search=&filter-sub-class=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-unlocked-content=). When you do so, choose a number of paladin spells equal to your Charisma modifier + half your paladin level, rounded down (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

I would recommend reading up on the [general spellcasting rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting) for 5th edition as your question seems to have some misconceptions about how spell level and class level are related.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever rolled a character in 5e so it's likely that yes I do have some things wrong. I agreed to try and dm a one shot for my wife and I so we could get used to the rules before joining a more experienced group.

Comment: @mjmiller1824 Good on you for taking on the DM role. [The basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) are all available online for free. Have a read and feel free to ask questions about anything that confuses you. Once you hit 20 rep you can join us in [chat] for less structured advice. Good luck!